# Android Studio live template not working

Tags: android, templates, android-studio

I've created a Live Template under the "user" template group. I've set the Abbreviation to "setpref". It is listed on my list of Live Templates, but it is not available when I type "setpref" in  a code window. I'm guessing that I've missed something obvious but can't work out what.
Any ideas??

Comment: Please make sure that you've correctly specified the context for your live template (the set of languages in which it's available).

Comment: @yole can you make an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 10):

To make the Live Templates appear again, do the following:

1) Open Editor>Live Templates

2) When you find templates with issues, select them and do step 4-6

3) At the bottom, click Change where it says "Applicable in..."

4) In the popup, under Java select statement to make templates like logd, logm,             logw etc be available inside methods.

5) Select declaration to make templates like logt available in classes' field declarations.

Done!

Visit this link - https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3n9nis/issues_with_live_templates_in_android_studio_try/?st=j0pjkc4w&sh=e84eb254

Have fun ! :) It works.

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure that you've correctly specified the context for your live template (the set of languages in which it's available).

Answer (score 0):

If you see below the editor of live templates this sentence.

---

No applicable contexts.

1. click on "Define" beside the text.
2. select the language you coding.
3. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin:

1. Open the "Preferences" menu item
2. Search "Live Templates"
3. Put your template below Kotlin set